# merge tables in Loop using R

Tags: r, loops

I have a simple question regarding a loop that I wrote. I want to access different files in different directories and extract data from these files and combine into one table. My problem is that my loop is not adding the results of the different files but only updating with the species that is currently in the loop. Here it is my code:

```
for(i in 1:length(splist.par))
{ 

  results<-read.csv(paste(getwd(),"/ResultsR10arcabiotic/",splist.par[i],"/","maxentResults.csv",sep=""),h=T)

  species <- splist.par[i]
  AUC <- results$Test.AUC[1:10]
  AUC_SD <- results$AUC.Standard.Deviation[1:10]
  Variable <- "a"
  Resolution <- "10arc"
  table <-cbind(species,AUC,AUC_SD,Variable,Resolution)
}
```

This is probably an easy question but I am not an experienced programmer. Thanks for the attention
Gabriel

Comment: You could probably do with a few more tags there and some formatting - what language is this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `lapply` to get the desired data from each file and add the Species information, and then combine with `rbind`.  Something like this (untested):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(splist.par, function(x) {
  d <- read.csv(file.path("ResultsR10arcabiotic", x, "maxentResults.csv"))
  d <- d[1:10, c("Test.AIC", "AIC.Standard.Deviation")] 
  names(d) <- c("AUC", "AUC_SD")
  cbind(Species=x, d, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}))
```

Comment: If this is helpful, click the up-arrow to vote for it.  If it solved your problem, click the check mark to let others know that this worked.  (You can do both.)  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

@Aaron's `lapply` answer is good, and clean.  But to debug your code:  you put a bunch of data into `table` but overwrite `table` every time.  You need to do

```
table <-cbind(table, species,AUC,AUC_SD,Variable,Resolution)
```

BTW,  since `table` is a function in R,  I'd avoid using it as a variable name.  Imagine:

```
table(table)
```

:-)

Comment: Good clarification, thanks.  But `rbind(table, cbind(species, AUC, AUC_SD, Variable, Resolution))`, I think.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments this was very helpful!